# GraphQL batching with logic

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have the following situation in GraphQL schema:

```
type User {
  id: Float
  name: String
  cityId: Float
}

type City {
  id: Float
  country: String
}
```

On client I need information about `User` and `City`. But in order to load `City` I have to know its id, so I can't just batch these requests. Is it possible to make batch request with logic, so from client I make one request with two queries and maybe add some addition info that when the first request is done take id from it and then make another request.

After that both User and City go to client. It is so to say inner join, so I would like to have one request to load connected data.

I can't change the schema, but I can add libs and so on to client or server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> PS. sorry i have just noticed that you stated that you cannot change
>   the schema. I will leave it there for future reference, but it cannot
>   be applied on your problem probably.

i would suggest to rearrange your schema as follows. I do not have enough information if it would satisfy your needs. But i would suggest this.

```
type User {
 id: Float
 name: String
 city: City
 #for this city field there will be additional resolver binded to data loader
}
type City {
  id: Float
  country: String
}
```

This way the query will look like as follows

```
query getUsers {
  users {
    id
    name
    city {
      id
      country
    }
  }
}
```

There can be used UserConnection from Relay spec, but let's keep it simple for now.
On server side you will then need to implement two resolvers ... first is request for user list and then resolver for city field. Please note that resolvers have seperate context. In order to avoid N+1 requests problem and batch requests city requests to 1. It would be useful to implement [data loader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader) for cities to reduce the number of requests to database. The simple schema would be

1. User resolver, fetch users and return them in users resolver. CityId
   is part of the payload for each use
2. Because city is second level of selection set you will receive each user in the first argument in the resolver function. You will use countryId to pass it to Countries data loader
3. Countries data loader will batch requests for each counry together. Data loader will transform the countryIds into country values and return them for each user.
4. GraphQL server will resolve the whole query and each city will be assigned to each user

This is the best approach that i know to deal with this and will also leads you to better architecture of your schema as you will leverage normalization of your appollo store and in my opinion it is easier to work with this format of the data on frontend as well. I hope that i did not miss something in your post and this information will be useful for you. The whole point is to just nest the country into the user, which leads to N+1 request problem and reduce the performance issue of N+1 problem with data loaders.